# Vue call all mounted functions (API calls) simultaneously

Tags: vue.js

Good morning,

currently my `mounted` looks like this :

```
  mounted: function () {
    this.getRequestTypes()
    this.getReports()
    this.getQuotes()
  }
```

Behind this are the following functions:

```
    getReports: function (date = this.date, requestType = 0) {
      this.loading = true
      this.$http.get('/reports/month/' + date + '/' + requestType)
          .then(function (response) {
            this.loading = false
...
          }.bind(this))
    },
    getQuotes: function (date = this.date2, requestType = 0) {
      this.loading = true
      this.$http.get('/reports/quote/month/' + date + '/' + requestType)
          .then(function (response) {
            this.loading = false
            console.log(response.data)
          }.bind(this))
    },
    getRequestTypes: function () {
      this.$http.get('/addresses/requesttypesreports')
          .then(function (response) {
            this.itemsRequestTypes = response.data
          }.bind(this))
    },
```

Currently, the way it behaves is that the functions (API) calls are processed one after the other, which causes a slight delay.
Is there a possibility to execute the calls all at the same time?

Comment: Technically, those methods are already called at the same "time" (i.e., in the same macrotask of the event loop). Why do you think they're called synchronously?

Comment: For instance, check out the network waterfall in DevTools for this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OJpqppZ).

Comment: @tony19 because I see that the first content is display and then after 2 more seconds the second

Comment: If you maybe want to "finish" them all at the same point, and set your `loading` to false only after they've all completed (they start simultanously already, but maybe the API takes more time for one action), you can use `Promise.all` .

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Promise.all` and run the API call individually with an async function.

```
this.loading=true;
Promise.all([this.getRequestTypes, this.getReports, this.getQuotes]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
  this.loading = false;
});
```

The methods should be async.

```
getReports: async function (date = this.date, requestType = 0) {
       await this.$http.get('/reports/month/' + date + '/' + requestType)
          .then(function (response) {
          }.bind(this))
    },
    getQuotes: async function (date = this.date2, requestType = 0) {
      await this.$http.get('/reports/quote/month/' + date + '/' + requestType)
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data)
          }.bind(this))
    },
    getRequestTypes: async function () {
      await this.$http.get('/addresses/requesttypesreports')
          .then(function (response) {
            this.itemsRequestTypes = response.data
          }.bind(this))
    },
```

Comment: Methods shouldn't necessarily be async. They just need to return a promise, while they originally don't.

Comment: I tried it. But no content is loading right now.

Comment: @Estus as they don't return anything so I prefer to use async await

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) using [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
mounted: function () {
    this.getAllReports()
  },
  methods:{
     getAllReports: function() {
            this.loading = true;
            Promise.all([this.getRequestTypes(), this.getReports(), this.getQuotes()])
           .then(data => {
              // Use data here
              this.loading = false;
            })
          .catch(err => {
            // user err to display message
            this.loading = false;
          });
     }
  }
```

And update all three functions like below

```
//-----------v------------
getReports: async function (date = this.date, requestType = 0) {
      this.loading = true
//------v------------
      await this.$http.get('/reports/month/' + date + '/' + requestType)
          .then(function (response) {
          }.bind(this))
    },
```